# Plugin for Sublime to see breadcrumbs

Tags: ember.js, plugins, sublimetext3

Does anyone know of a plugin where I can get the breadcrumbs of a file I am working on. 
Lets say I am working on app/controllers/admin/crs/abc, So I can see this info at the top or start of the window. 
I am using ember and due to pod structure its hard to know which file I am working as all of them have different folders but same names.

Answer (score 5):

Simply edit your user preferences and add

```js
"show_full_path": true
```

and the full path of the file will appear in Sublime's titlebar when the file is active.

Compare with the setting (OS X):

[image: title]

to without it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but still, I think this is an interesting Package that not many people know of.
On top of @mattdmo answer, you might even want to check the breadcrumbs for a nested structure (pretty much like you'd do in VS Code): just install [Breadcrumbs](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Breadcrumbs) for Sublime Text. Not as cool, but it works ok.

[image]